# For loop to reference external .txt file contents

Tags: python, api, loops

I am fairly new to python so please be kind. I am a network administrator but have been tasked with automating several processes of ours using python.

I am trying to take a list of networks id's and plug them into a URL using 
For loop.

```
file = open('networkid.txt', 'r')

def main(file):
   for x in file:
      print(x)`
link = ('https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/') +(Network ID) ('/syslogServers')
```

Each line in the .txt files contains a network ID, and I need that ID to be injected where (Network ID) is in the script, then I need the script to run the rest of the script *not posted here* and continue this until all ID's have been exhausted.

The current example layout is not how my script is setup but bits and pieces are cut to give you an idea of what I am aiming for.

To clarify the question at hand, how do I reference each line in the text file, which each line contains a network ID that I need to inject into the URL. From there, I am trying to establish a proper For Loop to continue this process until all network ID's in the list has been exhausted.

Comment: What is your question, though? It's not clear to me at all what we are supposed to be helping with.

Comment: I have a network ID in a .txt file, thousands of them. I have a script which contains a URL and I need to retrieve the ID from the .txt file and inject it into the URL. Then using a For loop I need it to run through all network id's in that file that I am referencing. Does that make sense? This script is used to obtain syslog settings for each Meraki network.

Comment: `x` will contain the network ID.

Comment: But you need to strip off the newlines.

Comment: That makes sense as a statement, I'm still not sure what you are _asking_ for us to help with. You already half concatenated the URLs. What exactly are we supposed to be helping with?

Answer (score 0):

`x` contains the network ID after you strip off the newline.

```
for line in file:
    networkID = line.strip()
    link = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/' + networkID + '/syslogServers'
    # do something with link
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now I just need to have each printed line to be injected into the URL during each loop. Any suggestions?